# Pixi.js: Is there a way to analyze javascript as it's running without writing lots of console.logs?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, pixi.js

I'm trying to analyze and understand a huge bunch of js code, it's written in pixi.js. Is there a way to watch the code as it fires? To see the functions as they fire?  I tried working with Profiles in Chrome Developer Tools but it just told me about the cookies :D Maybe I'm not using it correctly.

Or is there a way to write a console.log that logs the js function firing, and then I can just keep changing the function name?

Comment: I think [this](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging) might be good. It's Google's explanation for Chrome Devtools with JavaScript debug explained in detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! It's called a debugger and can be found by going to 'sources' in chrome dev tools: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging